# Which bundles and dependencies do I need to run an OrientDb client in an OSGi container

Tags: osgi, orientdb

I am working on an OSGi application using a OrientDb database. I'm now trying to get the OrientDb client running in our OSGi container.

The OrientDb site states which jars/dependencies your application will need when using a OrientDb client. [OrientDb documentation about this](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html).

Some of the jars mentioned are OSGi bundles, some are not. I imported all the jars which are OSGi bundles and wrapped the non-OSGi jars into an OSGi bundle. So all these jars are loaded in the OSGi container. When I start the container it complains about the bundle com.orientechnologies.orientdb-graphdb requiring the import package com.orientechnologies.orient.server.

I don't think I should import het orientdb-server-*.jar in the OSGi container, because that will mean I'll import pretty much a whole OrientDb server instance, while I only want to use a OrientDb client.

Why does the orientdb-graphdb-*.jar depend on the orientdb-server-*.jar?
What bundles do I need to load to use the OrientDb client?

OrientDb version I use is 2.1.9

Answer (score 1):

There is an [experimental apache karaf feature for orientdb](https://gist.github.com/rkettelerij/7427673). Try with these bundles. The good new is that all the jars mentioned there are already bundles.

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB libraries already come with OSGi bundle information, but unfortunately the Blueprints API libs don't, there is even an issue on that with a pull request but it was declined as the Blueprints devs don't think it's worth adding 2-3 lines of meta-information to the MANIFEST.MF, which is a real pity (and PITA).

In my project, I have a working configuration with the official OrientDB libs:
* orientdb-core
* orientdb-client
* orientdb-graphdb
* orientdb-enterpise (only needed for versions < 2.2)

and I wrapped the Blueprints libs using the excellent [OPS4J Tipi project](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.tipi) (have to prepare a git pull request still).
There's a google-guava dependency that also has to be wrapped.